# Is there a meaning to the name YoRHa?

Tags: nier-automata

I ve finished NieR Automata two days ago, and can't get enough of it.

I am reading a lot about the YoRHa project, ect... But I can't seems to find the meaning of the name itself.

It look like an acronym to me, but I have no clue of what it could be, or if it mean anything or if it is just a cool sounding name.

Why was the name YoRHa chosen, and if for a reason, what is it meaning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the [NieR: Automata wiki](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/NieR:_Automata), the name YoRHa originated from a [stage play](http://firesanctuary.com/yorha/) under the same name, which became the foundation of the masterpiece of a game

> What is "YoRHa"?
>
> The storyline of "YoRHa" was the product of Yoko Taro. He collaborated with MONACA and DearStage among others to create a story that involves traditional Japanese idols who sing, dance, and later perform in the YoRHa stage play. This story later became the basis for the game NieR:Automata.

The [YoRHa Stage Play](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/YoRHa_Stage_Play) is about the events that take place prior to NieR: Automata

> Written by Yoko Taro, YoRHa is a stage play which tells of the events before NieR: Automata. Taking place in 11,941, it tells the story of the Pearl Harbor Descent Mission during the 14th Machine War

As to why "YoRHa" is capitalized the way it is, as stated in [this](http://firesanctuary.com/blog/2016/04/28/famitsu-april-25-interview/) interview (credits to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/nier/comments/5ywfz3/is_yorha_an_abbreviation/)), Yoko Taro kept this a secret

> Yoko: For NieR, it was just a design choice regarding the logo. I thought it felt a little light, which is why we decided to capitalize it. As for the YoRHa logo… that’s secret.